# Android 2.1: How do I bring the soft keyboard manually?

Tags: android

I've a form that occupies upper half of the screen and I want to show the keyboard
at the bottom half all the time. How do I do that?

(Android 2.1, NexusOne)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to control the soft-keyboard in your code you can use the InputMethodManager to call it up and dismiss it.  getSystemService() is a call on the Activity.

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(activeView, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible">`

For more info see [this page](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Answer (score 0):

try View v = getWindow().getDecorView();